# Syntax highlighting when viewing code in Android app

Tags: bug, status-completed, syntax-highlighting, code-block, android-app

When I view question/answer, you can see the code blocks with syntax highlighting. But if I click on the code block to be able to horizontally scroll, all syntax highlighting is lost and the text color is a very hard to read grey on a white background. Is it possible to get syntax highlighting on the code block view, or at least black text?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What about Whitespace? Can we have highlighting there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! It's fixed and will go out in the next update:

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you work for Stack Exchange if you've got this screenshot. If so, can we get you a diamond?

Comment: @StevenV Just got it, was a little delayed in my actions ;)